# Unfortunately, app has stopped,how can I make this work onCreateView?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Previously, I had a similar issue, app crashes when trying to access (or findByID), it turned out, I've put the textview in the wrong method, Now I have only one method, and I am working with a fragment, the method `onCreateView` and my app keeps crashing:

```
public class InfoFragment extends Fragment {


    public InfoFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

       TextView n = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.nama);
       n.setText("Some String");

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_info, container, false);
    }

}
```

Originally, I had the line looking like this :

```
 TextView n = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.nama);
```

However,the compiler gave me an error saying it can't find the method `findViewById`, so some research showed that I should add `getView()` , I did, and the error disappeared, but now the app is crashing, any ideas?

Comment: Basically, you're not inflating your `Fragment`'s view. Please refer to https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#UI for a tip on how to inflate its view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@Override 
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_info, container, false);

   TextView n = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.nama);
   n.setText("Some String");

   return view;
}
```

You don't have a view yet in that part of code. Inflate it first and use after.

Comment: Thanks a lot for help, it helped

Comment: Please close question with marking one of answers as right one.

Answer (score 1):

Inflate your layout first, then you can use it to find the TextView:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_info, container, false);
    TextView n = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.nama);
    n.setText("Some String");

    return rootView;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for help, it helped